Are connected components clopen?
I was thinking about this proposition from a book:
"The components of $X$ are disjoint nonempty closed subsets whose union is $X$,
and thus they form a partition of $X$"
And I wondered:

Aren't components by definition clopen? Then why would they only  mentioned that they are closed ?. Is it implicit that they are talking about closed in the subspace topology?

In my book "A maximal connected subset of $X$ (i.e., a connected subset that is not properly contained in any larger connected subset) is called a component (or connected component) of $X$".
I made the following example to illustrate my point
$A=A_1\cup A_2$ , $A_1=[0,1], A_2= (2,3)$, then by definition the open subsets in the subspace topology  of $A$ are of the form $A\cap U$ for some $U$ open subset of $\Bbb R$. Since $(-0.1,1.1)$ and $ (1.9,3.1)$ are open in $\Bbb R$,  $A_1=[0,1]=A \cap (-0.1,1.1)$  and  $A_2=[2,3]=A \cap (1.9,3.1)$  are open in $A$.
Also $A\setminus A_1=A_2$ is open (in the subspace topology) so, $A_1$ is closed(in the subspace topology), and analogously $A_2$ is closed(in the subspace topology)
So $A_1$ and $A_2$ are clopen (in the subspace topology).

Isn't the proposition from the book in contradiction with what is written in pag 2 of these lecture notes (https://math.uchicago.edu/~womp/2008/pointset2008.pdf)
"Connected components are not generally open or closed" ? the proposition above from the books says connected components are closed, so it is not true that they are generally not closed, isn't it?

They give the followign example" For example,
the connected component of $0$ in $\Bbb Q$ is the set $\{0\}$, which is neither open or closed."
But I don't really see why $\{0\}$ isn't closed, Aren't singletons in Hausdorff spaces closed? the complement would be $\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\}$, and isn't an open  ball of rational numbers centered at any $x \neq 0$ s.t $0$ isn't in the ball an open ball contained in $\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\}$?making $\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ open and therefore the singleton closed?

Maybe in the second source they did not mean open or close in the subset topology? Also if all your connected components are open, you can prove that they are also closed.But I am not sure the converse is true given infinitely many connected components

@julio_es_sui_glace  I think you're right. I thought that it was implicit to refer to the subspace topology. I added an example that I don't fully unbderstand though

I agree with you singletons are definitely closed in Hausdorff spaces. How reliable is your source? Also this has the advantage of giving non open connected components, maybe they made some mistake

@julio_es_sui_glace The source is the same link I posted. It just showed up when I looked it up, and it is from a respected university and I couldn't find any other source explaining that ${0}$ is not closed. There are only posts on this site explaining that it is not open.

The connected components of a space $X$ are closed subsets of $X$. You can find a proof in any book about general topology. In general they are not open in $X$. As an example take $X = \mathbb Q$. The claim in your lecture notes that $\{0\}$ is neither open or closed is wrong. This answers question 2. Perhaps the author of the lecture notes wanted to say that path components are in general neither open nor closed (which is true). But also in that case the $\mathbb Q$-example is wrong.

Aren't components by definition clopen?

No. They are defined as maximal connected subsets of $X$. It requires a proof that they are closed, and they are in general not open. However, if $X$ has only finitely many components, they are open because the complement of any component $C$ is the union of the finitely many components distinct from $C$.

"The components of X  are disjoint nonempty closed subsets whose union is X, and thus they form a partition of X"- In this statement, is it implicit that it is closed in the subspace topology?

@some_math_guy what do you mean by "implicit"? This is something that has to be proved.

@freakish I meant that closed means closed in the subspace topology and not in the original topology when X is a subset of a bigger space. I was thinking of my example, where the sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ don't have to be open nor closed in the topology over $\Bbb R$ but they are closed in the subspace topology.

For definiteness I use the following definition: Let $X$ be a topological space. Define an equivalence relation $E$ on $X$ by: $x\mathrel{E}y$ if for any clopen subset $U \subseteq X$ we have $x,y\in U$ or $x,y\in X\setminus U$. Then the equivalence classes are the components. By definition they are closed (they are intersections of clopen (hence closed) sets). They are not necessarily open. The easiest example might be $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$, here $\{0\}$ is a closed, non-open component.
Edit: I just realized that the above defintion is sometimes referred to as defining the quasi-components of $X$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space).
The usual definition goes like this: Let $X$ be a topological space. Define an equivalence relation $F$ on $X$ by: $x\mathrel{F}y$ if there exists a connected subspace $C\subseteq X$ (with the subsapce topology) that contains both $x$ and $y$. (It is easy to see that $F\subseteq E$, but the converse is not always true.) The classes of $F$ are the components of $X$.
It is an excercise to see that $F$ is actually an equivalence relation and that the classes of $F$ are connected and closed (as subsets of $X$).

1=In what book can I find this definition of components? 2) "By definition they are closed (they are intersections of clopen (hence closed) sets)" which definition?what are the intersecting clopen  sets? They would have to be a finite quantity for the argument to work. 3)  How do you know ${\0}$ is non-open ?


see edit 2) the definition I stated, the class of x is the intersection of all clopen sets containing x (this set is always closed - no finiteness is needed) - with the other definition the argument is different: First show that an F-class is connected and then show that the closure of a connected subset is again connected. 3) Any open subset containing $0$ is infinite by definition of the subset topology.

